# How to call another function in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm relatively new to flask and I'm building a web app. I've got one page (called home) and I want to do things once I get input from the user in the form of a form. Once I get that input, I've tried to call other functions that will do things with that user input, but I'm getting an internal server error. Note, my html file is very simple and it just gives the user a form to fill out. Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


def webScrape():
    #scrapes stuff



def sendMessage(body, subject, to):
    #sends a message
    

def driver():
    #meat of the algorithm

@app.route("/", methods =["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        #get info from html form
        first_name = request.form.get("name")
        last_name = request.form.get("number")

        #regular algorithm
        driver()

        return "Will you even see this message?"

    return render_template("home.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I didn't include all of the code because that'd be too much and I think the problem lies in how things are set up than what's my actual code (since my py script runs fine not using flask).

Comment: Did you tell your HTML form where to submit to using the action= attribute? (Example: action="/form")

Comment: Python gets the info from html correctly. The problem lies in the python file. My question is am I calling other functions correctly in this file

Comment: From what I can tell, yes, but you should use a console log or print statement to make sure. Always validate your assumptions that it's even getting to that method call. From there you should be ok.

Comment: I have, this isn't the correct way to do this. There's something I'm missing in order to call functions

Comment: I'm not sure what error you're getting then because it should work as you have it

Answer (score 0):

You can use debug=True in app.run function. It will give you the correct error.

```
app.run(debug=True)
```